SQL Alchemy error in writing custom cursor with visit_select() and results not getting parsed by session.query(table).all
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'compile_options'
  File "/usr/....../main.py", line 26, in <module>
    parsed_records = session.query(Member).all()
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'compile_options'


Hi,
I have a non-standard database which doesn't have any module available in sqlalchemy and I am attempting to write customized code for the same to utilize ORM capabilities of sqlalchemy.
Heres what I have done so far (that works),

Create custom dialect (return driver for the target database) and a custom compiler.
Custom compiler inherits SQLCompiler with implementation for visit_select(self, select, **kwargs) - this converts SQL like statement to target database native select statement
create custom connection and custom cursor
custom cursor has execute function which returns result as a text blob so I wrote text parser to convert this result to list of tuples.
Next I got error for "description" attribute being empty so I wrote implementation to build description using class from model (i.e. table column names, types etc)
Now i am stuck with the error about "compile options" and I am not sure where this implementation exists and why obj is 'None' when framework attempts to use compile options

